# MYSQLi Count and Group by

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have this table (sample)

```
|---id---|---place---|---admin---|
|    1   |    Q      |    AJ     |
|    2   |    p      |    PM     |
|    3   |    w      |    AJ     |
|    4   |    t      |    TY     |
|    5   |    u      |    AJ     |
```

I want to count how many places each admin control using MYSQLi not mysql.
I have searched and all what I found is MYSQL and using COUNT(*) and when I am trying to use it, does not work.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT admin, COUNT(admin) as 'amount' FROM tablename GROUP BY admin");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    echo "Name: " .  $row['admin'] . " - ". $row['amount'] . "<br />";
```

Using `count` + `GROUP by` you can get the amount of times each admin appears in the table.